# C# Linq method calculate balance

Tags: c#, linq

I have a transaction model entity like this:

```
public class TransactionModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Withdraw { get; set; }
    public int? Deposit { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I use `TransactionViewModel` class to show data in view that just only have one property more than `TransactionModel` class and that is `Balance`

I want to show balance when every transaction is shown.

```
       Withdraw         Deposit         Balance

1)     -                100             100
2)     50               -               50
3)     10               -               40
```

I use linq `Select` method but when I want to calculate balance I couldn't use `Sum()` method.

```
 public IEnumerable<TransactionViewModel> 
 CreateTransactionViewModel(IEnumerable<TransactionModel> transactions)
    {
        return transactions.Select(x => new TransactionViewModel
        {
            Id= x.Id,
            Date = x.Date,
            Deposit = x.Deposit,
            Withdraw = x.Withdraw,
            Balance = //...
        });
    }
```

**Update**

I'm not sure using `Sum()` is the best way to calculate balance or not. I just want to have a balance of each transaction.

Comment: You couldnt use Sum with what code? It would help if you would explain the logic.

Comment: Show us your Sum query and the result of it, exception or something else?

Comment: Balance should be a get only property in the TransactionViewModel performing a difference between Deposit and Withdraw

Comment: Rather than computing it every time you execute this query, you probably just want to compute the balance every time a new transaction is added and store it in the DB.

Comment: @TimSchmelter change solution to `+= (x.Deposit.GetValueOrDefault() - x.Withdraw.GetValueOrDefault())` and undelete answer :) nice trick with deposit - withdraw btw

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: i have deleted it because it might have a performance impact because i need to use Linq-To-Objects

Comment: @TimSchmelter I believe it should not, because transactions will be loaded into memory anyway, but you can check :)

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate it like this:

```
return transactions.Select(x => new TransactionViewModel
        {
            Id= x.Id,
            Date = x.Date,
            Deposit = x.Deposit,
            Withdraw = x.Withdraw,
            Balance = transactions.Where(y => y.Id <= x.Id).Sum(z => z.Deposit ?? 0 - z.Withdraw ?? 0)
        });
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly. You can see result here : https://ibb.co/f2Wrh5

Comment: Where are the IDs in that output?

Comment: This code makes assumptions about identifier and record order that are untenable in my opinion. If you are going to assume an order, one would think you would assume it is by date desc, but that is an assumption nevertheless. We have no idea how Id is populated -- it might be an identity or it might not. You are also calculating a running balance, and the example data above does not make clear to me whether it should be a row-only balance, total balance, or running balance. OP should specify exactly the type of balance to show in order to improve quality of answers.

Comment: @Trioj You are right. That assumption was not really right. I missinterpreted the 1), 2) and 3) as the IDs. But I think the example is very clearly a running total

Comment: @romano-zumbé Lol, actually my problem is assuming order too. I assume I am looking from the bottom up to view the history of what happened, when it is in fact top-down. Viewed top-down, it is clearly a running balance.

Answer (score 1):

Why use Linq?  You can do this with a simple loop.

```
int balance = 0;
int row = 1;
List<BalanceModel> result = new List<BalanceModel>();
foreach(TransactionModel tm in list)
{
    balance += tm.Deposit - tm.Withdraw;
    BalanceModel bm = new BalanceModel()
    {
        Row = row,
        Withdraw = tm.Withdraw,
        Deposit = tm.Deposit,
        Balance = balance,
    };
    result.Add(bm);
    row++;
}
```

Comment: Thats not really simpler than linq. Its a lot more code

Comment: @RomanoZumbé, it's more lines of code, but it's simpler than anything with this in it `transactions.Where(y => y.Id <= x.Id).Sum(z => z.Deposit ?? 0 - z.Withdraw ?? 0)`

Comment: I do not agree. The linq representation makes it a lot clearer, what is happening there. You can almost read what is going on like in a sentence. But that is up to OP. Your solution is as good as mine. Just a thing of personal preference

Comment: @RomanoZumbé Your solution is also exponentially more expensive to compute than this solution, as you continually re-compute the same sums over and over again.

Comment: I like LINQ, but sometimes when you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail. I.e. calculating sum of all previous transactions for each transaction can cause performance problem (but remember 20/80 rule before optimization). You can of course capture balance in the LINQ query and use it in select, but that will introduce side effects to the query, which is not good too. I personally prefer loops if I do modification of some variables or query items

Comment: If there is a programmer who is incapable of reading and understanding this code at your company versus the LINQ code, then I strongly feel that you should fire that programmer. I do not believe that the LINQ example is in fact more clear, just more concise.